# How to handle retrofit call that returns multiple models

Tags: android, retrofit

I am making an API call that returns an array of distinct object that have different attributes:

```
[
    {
        "likesCount": 17771,
        "sharesCount": 8823,
        "liked": false,
        "shared": false,
        "mediaType": "video",
        "mediaWidth": 1920,
        "mediaHeight": 1080,
        "mediaAspectRatio": "16:9",
        "mediaVideoUriDash": "https://d339b3x89fwe5u.cloudfront.net/2685322c-52cb-4c45-b671-63e607f17c97/dash/community-tile-video-1600081282.mpd",
        "mediaVideoUriHls": "https://d339b3x89fwe5u.cloudfront.net/2685322c-52cb-4c45-b671-63e607f17c97.m3u8",
        "mediaVideoCoverImageUri": "https://d339b3x89fwe5u.cloudfront.net/2685322c-52cb-4c45-b671-63e607f17c97/thumbnails.jpg"

},{
        "createdDate": "2020-09-14T11:01:20.025583Z",
        "createdTimestampEpochInMilliseconds": 1600081280026,
        "updatedDate": "2020-09-14T11:10:41.9218332Z",
        "updatedTimestampEpochInMilliseconds": 1600081841922,
        "id": "2490fc73-e17a-4a77-8905-b3e945c89fbf",
        "name": "Test",
        "url": "https://google.com/",
        "categoryType": "community",
        "weight": 5400,
        "isLikable": true,
        "isSharable": true,
        "isFullWidth": true
   
}
]
```

How to I parse them into different local objects?

Comment: This violates Array DS . Its should be collection of Similar data types . You need to change the API response if u can't then you have write a custom parser which will be a pain i guess with this arrangment.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Any known examples of a custom parser?

Comment: I don't think writing custom parser is good idea . Since you do not know which object is the next in Array . They should come under separate arrays .